# Как создать css анимацию(3d карточка)?

Tags: css3, html5

Дайте совет в реализации следующей задачи.
Есть два изображения. нужно сделать так что бы когда одно изображение переворачивается показывалось другое. при hover я смог это реализовать, однако необходимо сделать так что бы анимация проигрывалась без hover.
код при наведении рабочий

```css
.about-me__image {
  position: relative;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.about-me__image:hover .front {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.about-me__image:hover .back {
  transform: rotateY(360deg);
}

.front {
  position: relative;
  transition: 2s;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.back {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: 2s;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.about-me__image img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="about-me__image slideInLeft wow">
  <div class="front">
    <img src="https://picua.org/images/2018/11/17/a1efa87050160308e0afe15637b08191.png" alt="a1efa87050160308e0afe15637b08191.png" border="0" />
    <div class="back">
      <img src="https://picua.org/images/2018/11/17/560b24bae099abf1bacdbafb162d62b2.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

код без наведения

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}

.about-me__image {
  position: relative;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.front {
  position: relative;
  transition: 2s;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  animation-name: frontfase;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  /*animation-fill-mode: forwards;*/
  /* animation-iteration-count: 1; */
}

@keyframes frontfase {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
}

@keyframes backfase {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}

.back {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: 2s;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  animation-name: backfase;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  /* animation-iteration-count: infinite; */
}

.about-me__image img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="about-me__image slideInLeft wow">
  <div class="front">
    <img src="https://picua.org/images/2018/11/17/a1efa87050160308e0afe15637b08191.png" alt="a1efa87050160308e0afe15637b08191.png" border="0" />
    <div class="back">
      <img src="https://picua.org/images/2018/11/17/560b24bae099abf1bacdbafb162d62b2.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Как сделать что бы был такой же эффект как при наведении, сейчас как бы видно заднюю часть изображения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
  background: #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.about-me__image {
  position: relative;
  perspective: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.foto-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  animation: rotate 3s infinite ease-in-out running;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.front {
  transform: rotateY(360deg);
}

@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotateY(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotateY(180deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotateY(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="about-me__image slideInLeft wow">
  <div class="foto-wrapper">
    <img class="back" src="https://picua.org/images/2018/11/17/560b24bae099abf1bacdbafb162d62b2.jpg">
    <img class="front" src="https://picua.org/images/2018/11/17/a1efa87050160308e0afe15637b08191.png" alt="a1efa87050160308e0afe15637b08191.png" />

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Очевидно так ??

Не забываем через autoprefixer пропускать

```css
.about-me__image {
  position: relative;
  perspective: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 100px;
}

.front {
  position: relative;
  transition: 2s;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.back {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: 2s;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.about-me__image img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.about-me__image .front {
  animation: front 4s linear infinite;
}

.about-me__image .back {
  animation: back 4s linear infinite;
  transform: rotateY(360deg);
}

@keyframes front {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateY(0);
  }
}

@keyframes back {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="about-me__image slideInLeft wow">

  <div class="front">
    <img src="https://picua.org/images/2018/11/17/a1efa87050160308e0afe15637b08191.png" alt="a1efa87050160308e0afe15637b08191.png" border="0" />
    <div class="back">
      <img src="https://picua.org/images/2018/11/17/560b24bae099abf1bacdbafb162d62b2.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: огромное вам спасибо за помощь. честно очень помогли. А не подскажете ли Вы еще такой момент, как сделать данную анимацию плавной. просто сейчас идет маленькая задержка. когда одна сторона сменяет другую( в центре заминка)

Comment: Алексей Биленко, ты же уже принял ответ, не красиво...  ответ Nikita, не хуже и тем более первый ответил...